# Why the getters in JSF2 Bean class are getting invoked even before submitting the Form elements?

Tags: forms, jsf-2

I have a simple JSF2.0 from page as shown below:

```
<h:body> 
    <div><center><h1><big><u>Java Learning Center</u></big></h1></center></div>
    <h2><big><a>Account Login</a></big></h2>
    <h:outputText value="#{userBean.errorMessage}" style="color:red; text-size:20"/>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid id="loginPanel" columns="3">
            <h:outputText value="Username" />
            <h:inputText value="#{userBean.username}" id="username" required="true" />
            <h:message for="username" style="color:red; text-size:18"/>
            <h:outputText value="Password" />
            <h:inputSecret value="#{userBean.password}" id="password" required="true" />
            <h:message for="password" style="color:red; text-size:18"/>
            <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{userBean.verifyUser()}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

And the Corresponding JSF2 Bean class is as shown:

```
@ManagedBean(name="userBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String errorMessage;
    //setters and getters
    public String verifyUser() {
      //User verification logic
    }
}
```

Now, when the form Page is rendered for the first time, I get the output in console as:

```
getErrorMessage()...
getUsername()...
getPassword()...
```

My Question is:

**1. Why these *getter* methods are invoked even before submitting the form Page?**

And when I am finally submitting the form page with values, then the console output is as follows:

```
getUsername()...
getPassword()...
setUsername()...
setPassword()...
verifyUser()...
```

Here,

**2. Why the getters are invoked before setters ?**. In my view the setters should be invoked first.

Comment: You need to have the values generated in order to put them in the HTML containing the form sent to the client.

Comment: To learn JSF, I recommend getting a sane book rather than relying on random tutorial found on the web. The code snippet doesn't look very good with that `<center>` tag which was deprecated in 1998. This is a very strong hint that the author's knowledge in web development must be taken with a bag of salt.

Comment: @BalusC, Thanks for pointing out that. I am new to web development (infact, new to whole world of programming). At the moment I am reading Core JSF2 Book, which stands there in your whishlist(on your blog). The above code was just my own. By the way your article on JSF debugging was great, Help a lot in clearing doubts about JSF lifecycle.